# Strange behaviour of an association

Tags: bugs, associations

This an almost MWE of a problem I encountered when working with associations.

```
asc1 = <| |>;
asc1[1] = Range[0, 9];
asc1[2] = Range[0, 9];
asc1
```

Out[150]= <|1 -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 2 -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}|>

The number 0 is in both values of this association, but Position does not find it:

```
Position[asc1, 0]
```

Out[151]= {}

Counts finds the number:

```
Count[asc1, 0, {2}]
```

Out[152]= 2

This is  a rather dirty trick to get Position working:

```
asc2 = ToExpression @ ToString @ asc1
```

Out[153]= <|1 -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 2 -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}|>

```
Position[asc2, 0]
```

Out[154]= {{Key[1], 1}, {Key[2], 1}}

Despite that Position works differently on both associations, Mathematica does not report that they are different:

```
asc1 === asc2
```

Out[155]= True

All comment is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share your version/platform? When I try in a Wolfram Cloud notebook, I get the expected behavior: `Position[asc1, 0]` yields `{{Key[1],1},{Key[2],1}}`.

Comment: @Pillsy Windows 10, Mathematica 13.2. Thanks for your information

Comment: Bug fixed in version 13.3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem seems to be the packed arrays generated by `Range`:

```
assoc = <|1 -> Range[0, 9], 2 -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}|>
assoc[1] === assoc[2]
Developer`PackedArrayForm[assoc]
Position[assoc, 0]
```

> [image]

I'd call that a bug, tbh. `Position` is definitely supposed to be able to look into packed arrays:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[assoc[1]]
Position[assoc[1], 0]
```

> True

> {{1}}

## Edit

It seems like the problem will be fixed in version 13.3 at least.